# Prove that if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Prove that if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$.

My justification for this question is as follows;

Suppose $F(\alpha^2)\subsetneq F(\alpha)$, we have $F \subsetneq F(\alpha^2) \subsetneq F(\alpha)$.

As $[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)][F(\alpha^2):F]$ and $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)]=2$ we would be end up with the case that $[F(\alpha):F]$ is a multiple of 2 i.e., even which contradicts given condition of $[F(\alpha):F]$ being odd.

So, $F(\alpha^2) =F(\alpha)$.

After doing this, i have seen for a solution on some webpage where he/she used criterion of minimal polynomial.

Please let me know Is my justification clear or there are any gaps in between?

Comment: It is clear. Personally, I would prefer to say that because $[F(\alpha) : F] = [F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^2)]\cdot [F(\alpha^2) : F]$ implies that $[F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^2)]$ is odd, hence $1$, since it is a divisor of $2$. But that's purely a matter of taste.

Comment: One very minor point, after supposing $F(\alpha^2) \subsetneq F(\alpha)$, you write $F \subsetneq F(\alpha^2)$. You don't have an argument to show that $F \neq F(\alpha^2)$ (would be easy to supply), but you don't use that, so just writing $F \subset F(\alpha^2)$ would be fine.

Comment: Thank You for that minor point :)

Regards, Praphulla

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your proof is correct but you don't need contradiction. If $F(\alpha) \neq F(\alpha^2)$ then $\alpha \notin F(\alpha^2)$. Thus consider the tower $[F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^2)][F(\alpha^2) : F]$. The first factor is at most two (because $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2 - \alpha^2$ and it is at least two because $\alpha \notin F(\alpha^2)$. By the tower law it follows $[F(\alpha) : F]$ is even.

Comment: Thank You :) Regards, Praphulla

Answer (score 0):

Another answer for variety:

Clearly $F(\alpha^2)\subseteq F(\alpha)$.  For the reverse inclusion, note that if
$$
0=\sum_ia_i\alpha^{2i+1}+\sum_jb_j\alpha^{2j}
$$
then
$$
\alpha=-\sum_jb_j\alpha^{2j}/\sum_ia_i\alpha^{2i}
$$
and $\alpha\in F(\alpha^2)$ if, say, the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ has any odd-power terms.