# Field extension with odd degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let  $F(a)$ be Field extension over $F$ such that $[F(a):F]=5$. I know that if $[F(a) : F]$ is odd then $F(a) = F(a^2)$. So how can I show that $F(a)= F(a^2+a+1)$. Could somebody please give me hints.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you prove that if $[F(a):F]$ is odd then $F(a)=F(a^2)$?

Comment: @Eric Wolfsey.. Here it is that I have found online http://www3.nd.edu/~ajorza/courses/m5c-s2013/homeworksol/h02sol.pdf or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451014/prove-that-if-f-alphaf-is-odd-then-f-alpha-f-alpha2

Comment: Well, can you try to give a similar proof for $F(a^2+a+1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same reason as with $F(a)=F(a^2)$, namely that $x^2+x+1$ has degree $2$ (i.e. between $1$ and $5$), so we know that

$$F\subset F(a^2+a+1)\subseteq F(a)$$

The first inclusion is proper because $[F(a^2+a+1):F]\big | [F(a):F]$, and we have the degree to be $1$ or $5$, but if $a^2+a+1=b\in F$, then $x^2+x+(1-b)$ is a smaller degree polynomial which $a$ satisfies, a contradiction.

Comment: @ Adam Hughhes.. Why is $F(a^2+a+1)\subseteq F(a)$?

Comment: @UserAb $F(a)$ is a field, so it is closed under multiplication and addition. $a\cdot a=a^2\in F(a)$ since it's a multiplication, the rest is addition

Comment: @ Adam Hughhes... wow thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
If $F\subset K\subset L$ are finite extensions, then
$$[L:F]=[K:F]\cdot[L:K]$$
If $[L:F]$ is prime, what can you say for $K$?