# Prove if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd, then $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is answered here,
[Prove that if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451014/prove-that-if-f-alphaf-is-odd-then-f-alpha-f-alpha2)

But I have a question about the last step.

I have $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)] = 1$, but I do not understand how we get

$F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^2)$ from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F \subseteq K$ is a field extension and $[K : F] = 1$, then $\dim_F(K) = 1$ by definition, and hence there is an $F$-basis of $K$ which has one element, say $\{ \beta \}$. Then $1 \in K$ can be written as an $F$-linear combination of $\beta$, i.e. there exists $a \in F$ such that $1 = a \beta$. Multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ yields that $\beta \in F$. Then since every element of $\gamma \in K$ is an $F$-linear combination of $\beta$, say $\gamma = c \beta$, it follows that $\gamma \in F$, hence $K \subseteq F$, so $F = K$.